# Bootstrap - links stop working in small resolutions

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

Links stop working in small resolution (under md). Here is example of my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/khybvw20/

```
    import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700&subset=latin,cyrillic);
body {
background-color: #ebebeb;
font: 17px/20px  'PT Sans Narrow', Arial, Tahoma,  sans-serif !important; 
}

a{
color: #0072c1 !important;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
color: #cc4343 !important;
text-decoration: underline !important;
}

.wrapper{
background-color: #fff;
}
```

Help me please to find out the problem.

Comment: Please minimize your code to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You add to many `.col` and not any `.row` and in general, your classes are pretty mixed up. Anyway, since you are using too many `.col` it means that you are also using too many `floats`, which means that you may have [clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix) some of them.

Your problem will be solved by just adding `overflow:hidden` to `.novostroyka-similar` but you **should** organize your code better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the links but with your HTML formatting. On a smaller resolution the floated elements are above your links and when you're trying to click the links you're actually clicking Похожие новостройки title inside the div novostroyka-similar.

Because of the HTML formatting there's alot of other problems too than just the links. I suggest you to go through your code and fix the formatting.